# ngx-charts colors does not show correctly Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, ngx-charts

I am trying to add color to the stacked bar graph using ngx-charts in angular 6. I use the array to add colors, But at each time color changes automatically. Whenever I request data color changes automatically. Is there any function or technique to assign colors to ngx-charts to each data manually in angular 6? 
Here is my HTML code

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked [scheme]="colorScheme"
                        [results]="multi" [gradient]="gradient" [xAxis]="showXAxis"
                        [yAxis]="showYAxis" [legend]="showLegend"
                        [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
                        [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel" [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
                        [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel" [view]="  " (select)="onSelect($event)">
```

Here is the array of colors I used in my typescript file

```
colorScheme = { 
domain: ['red', 'green','blue','pink','black']  };
```

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for this stuffed?????

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same problem then I used this property of ngx-charts:

In HTML:

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked
  [customColors]="ageGroupColors"
  .....
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked>
```

In Ts file:

```
ageGroupColors: [
  {name: 'Below 20 yrs', value: '#55C22D'},
  {name: 'Between 20 and 25 yrs', value: '#C1F33D'},
  {name: 'Between 25 and 30 yrs', value: '#3CC099'},
  {name: 'Between 30 and 35 yrs', value: '#AFFFFF'},
  {name: 'Between 35 and 40 yrs', value: '#8CFC9D'},
  {name: 'More than 40 yrs', value: '#26c6da'}
];
```

Hope it helps

Reference: [Github ngx-charts Demo](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/master/demo/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this

```
import { ColorHelper } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';


colors: ColorHelper
colorScheme = { 
  domain: ['red', 'green','blue','pink','black']  
};
schemeType: any;
yDomain = [0, 150]

getColors() {
  this.colors = new ColorHelper(this.colorScheme, this.schemeType, this.yDomain);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can do this](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/1673#issuecomment-1046530451)

```
import { Color, ScaleType } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';

colorScheme: Color = { 
    domain: ['#99CCE5', '#FF7F7F'], <= color can be anything
    group: ScaleType.Ordinal, 
    selectable: true, // => boolean (true / false)
    name: 'Customer Usage', 
};
```